# Limit a protected field to current assembley c# vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, protected, access-modifiers

Is there a way to limit the access to a protected field in the class, to the

Comment: You could just make it `internal`...if you're willing to deal with the fact that only classes inside your assembly will be able to see it.  Depends on what you need.

Comment: @rory.ap you're correct.

Comment: here is a link to the access specifiers which you can use ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal

Comment: @rory.ap you are right, I misread what OP wants.

Comment: The CLR supports it, the C# and VB.NET languages do not.  You'll have to use `sealed`.

Comment: @HansPassant but OP has protected _field_, how sealed would help?

Comment: Thank you I'm quoting the link " protected internal means "protected OR internal" I'm looking for protected AND internal.

Comment: @Evk - a protected field is accessible only to a derived class.  `sealed` prevents deriving a class.  It is the courageous and often correct choice, doesn't get used enough.  The language designers encouraged courage.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the requirement to design like this?

Comment: Good question ,Same reason why we design with protected , just keeping it  internal to better control the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot information on SO regarding this exact topic.

While `protected internal` means protected OR internal, you need protected AND internal ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063901/why-is-internal-protected-not-more-restrictive-than-internal) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal) questions for reference).

This is technically allowed on CLR level, but not supported in C# - see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964750/why-c-sharp-does-not-support-the-intersection-of-protected-and-internal-accessib) for example.

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856215/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-planned-private-protected-c-sharp-access-modifier) you can see plans for `private protected` - something like you need.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3238933/2170171) some technique to workaround this C# limitation.