# Protected properties of internal classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, access-modifiers

I am struggeling in making properties of classes defined as `internal` only setable by children (`protected`).

For clearity here an example:

```
internal class Foo
{
     internal int Bar { get; protected set; }

     internal Foo(int bar)
     {
         this.Bar = bar;
     }

     internal void Baz()
     {
         this.Bar++;
     }
}
```

This results in an error, which says, that the access of `Bar` needs to be more restrictive than the `set`-Accessor (which is correct, since `protected` allows access for classes outside of the assembly).

The only workaround I have here, is to declare Bar as `public`, but this is not, what I actually intended.  I probably need to modify `Bar` by some other methods (maybe even by children) than the constructor, so `readonly` wouldn’t work for me.

Is there any possibility to make properties of an `internal` class `internal` accessible for read and `internal` and `protected` accessible for write?

Edit: I am sorry, I just realized, that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941104/how-to-make-a-property-protected-and-internal-in-c) is basically the same as mine.  I somehow did not find it before.

Comment: `Foo` is internal, how classes from outside of assembly suppose to use it?

Comment: Hmm, that’s right, but then the `public` keyword would somehow give a false hint about the true accessibility of `Foo`.